# How to load a list from a json file?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have this data inside my text.txt:

```
[{"title": "T", "genre": "G", "director": "D", "year": "R"}]
```

When I try to load it this way (line 6):

```
class Movie:
    def __init__(self, **new_movie):
        movies = []
        with open ('movies.txt', 'r') as f:
            if f.read() != '':
                movies = json.load(f)
        if not verify_uniqueness(new_movie, movies):
            print('Movie has already been added.')
        else:
            self.title = new_movie['title']
            self.genre = new_movie['genre']
            self.director = new_movie['director']
            self.year = new_movie['year']
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How can I read the data?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error... just pasting the code as you have it and the json data in a `text.txt` file has worked for me both with py27 and py36. How have you called your script? If the name can be mistaken by some import from the json library, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: It works for me too, how you run your script ?

Comment: @jaumebonet I try to load json inside the \__init__ method of my Class. Could that be a problem?

Comment: For me it is that when copying the contents of the .txt to the question you have omitted certain characters. Upload to the cloud in a zip file and share the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open ('movies.txt', 'r') as f:
    if f.read() != '':
        movies = json.load(f)
```

Since `f` is essentially a generator, calling `f.read()` in the `if` condition consumes it, and by the time `json.load(f)` is called `f` is empty:

```
with open ('movies.txt') as f:
        print(f.read())
        # file content
        print(f.read())
        # ''
```

You have to store the file's content in a variable and then use `json.loads`:

```
with open('movies.txt') as f:
    content = f.read()
    if content:
        movies = json.loads(content)
```

Comment: I see. How can I rectify it?

Comment: just need to take it out. `json.load()` will take care of it on its own. Or you can save it to a variable to do the checks yourself.

Comment: Thank you both! :)